# Create Beowulf Cluster using 2 laptops

Tags: cluster

I've been looking into the possibility of creating a [Beowulf Cluster](http://www.beowulf.org).

> "Beowulf Clusters are scalable performance clusters based on commodity
>   hardware, on a private system network, with open source software
>   (Linux) infrastructure."

I don't have much experience, it just seems like a cool project. The thing is I don't own any desktop computers, would it be possible to do this using laptops?

I'm not sure if I need to give more details, please ask me anything that is relevant for this.

Comment: What operating system are you intending to use?

Answer (score 1):

Computationally laptops are almost identical to desktop counterparts, except for cooling and their harddrive characteristics.

An easy way to go would be to use rocksclusters

http://www.rocksclusters.org/

It would not be very practical to use notebooks to build clusters however.